# Sitecore 9 - Incrementing engagement value

Tags: xdb, tracking

The following code worked on Sitecore 8.x to increase Engagement Value programmatically:

```
Tracker.Current.Interaction.Value += value;
```

This code compiles and executes file on Sitecore 9.0.1, but after flushing my session and looking up the interaction in the xDB `Interactions` table, the `EngagementValue` column still has a value of 0. Is there an additional step needed with the Tracker on Sitecore 9?

Answer (score 4):

In Sitecore 9.x, the engagement value is a [calculated facet](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/facets/calculated-facets/engagement-measures.html).

If you want to increase the engagement value, you should add an event where you are setting the engagement value e.g.

```
using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
  try
  {
    var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, identifier);
    var contact = client.Get(reference, new ExpandOptions());

    int engagementValue = 10;

    var interaction = new XConnect.Interaction(contact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, channelId, userAgent);
    var engagementValueEvent = new Event(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
      EngagementValue = engagementValue
    };
    interaction.Events.Add(engagementValueEvent);

    client.AddInteraction(interaction);

    client.Submit();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    //
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use the client when working with the web tracker? Isn’t that done for me?

Comment: Correct, so in that case you would be registering an event. See https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-events/trigger-built-in-event-types.html and https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-events/trigger-custom-event/index.html